# Heap Corruption Detected (Simulating Dynamic Array with Static Array)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I wanna simulate dynamic array by using static array. However, when I delete some elements from the array and then try to add the array, I got an error saying 'Heap Corruption Detected'.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int INIT_SIZE = 5;
int MAX_SIZE = INIT_SIZE;
void printArray(int *arr, int n){
    cout << "n= " << n << " >> [";
    for(int i = 0; i < n ;i++){
        cout << arr[i];
        if ( i < n-1)
           cout << ",";
    }
    cout << "]\b\n";
}

bool deleteEl(int *&arr, int &n, int el){
int *newArr;
    bool found = false;
    int cnt = 0;
    if( n == 0){
       return false;
    }
    else{
       for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){
           if( arr[i] == el){
              found = true;
               cnt++;
           }
       }
       if( !found){
           return false;
       }
       newArr = new int[n-cnt];
       int k = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
          if( arr[i] != el){
            newArr[k++] = arr[i];
          }
       }
       n -= cnt;
   if (n <= (MAX_SIZE / 2) && (MAX_SIZE / 2) >= INIT_SIZE){
      MAX_SIZE /= 2;
   }
       delete[] arr;
       arr = newArr;
   }
   return true;
}

bool addEl(int *&arr, int &n, int el){
  int *newArr;
  if( n >= MAX_SIZE){
    newArr = new int[2 * MAX_SIZE];

    //std::copy(arr,arr+MAX_SIZE, newArr);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++){
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    n++;
    newArr[n-1] = el;
    MAX_SIZE *= 2;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = newArr;
}else{
    arr[n++] = el;
}

return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int *arr = new int[MAX_SIZE];
int n = 0;
int input = 0;
do{
   cout << "1. Add Element : " << endl;
   cout << "2. Del Element : " << endl;
   cout << "3. Exit : " << endl;
   cin >> input;

   if( input == 1){
       cout << "Enter new element : " << endl;
       int newEl;
       cin >> newEl;
       if( addEl(arr, n, newEl)){
           cout << "New Element Added. " << endl;
       }else{
           cout << "Add new element failed. " << endl;
       }

   }else if (input == 2){
       cout << "Enter deleted element : " << endl;
       int del;
       cin >> del;
       if( deleteEl(arr, n, del)){
           cout << "Deletion OK" << endl;
       }else{
           cout << "Deletion Fail. Data Not found." << endl;
       }
   }else if(input == 3){
       cout << "Program exiting ..." << endl;
   }else{
       cout << "Input is wrong. Enter correct input (1,2, or 3)." << endl;
   }
   printArray(arr,n);
}while(input != 3);

delete [] arr;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `addEl` function assumes that `arr` has at least `MAX_SIZE` elements, but your `deleteEl` function does not respect this assumption. There are other problems with this program: What if somebody creates two arrays? What if somebody adds to an array where `n > MAX_SIZE * 2`?

Comment: It's solved already..it's inside my deleteEl but not that problem.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Hinnant's stack allocator](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.h) and consider using STL instead of naked arrays.